# unable to dismiss progress bar in dialogfragment

Tags: android

I have a dialog fragment which consists of an AsyncTask class. I am able to show a progress bar inside the dialogfragment. But unable to stop it after some time. Is there any way?

```
class GetStatsFromUrl extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        //ProgressDialogFragment pf;
        ProgressBar p = null;

        String info, status;
        JSONObject json, json1, json2;



        /*String totalquestions,  notanswered,
                 correctanswered, wronganswered;*/




        String totalquestions, notanswered,
         correctanswered, wronganswered;

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //p =  new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            //p.setMessage("Loading..");
            //p.setIndeterminate(true);
           // p.setCancelable(false);
            //p.show();
            p=new ProgressBar(getActivity());
           // p.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         //p = (ProgressBar)      rootView.findViewById(R.id.loading_spinner);


            //p.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          // p.setMax(3000 -1);

        }



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // try {
            String url1 = "http://smarteach.com/questions/questions.svc/Learner_Qbank_Stats_Today/val1="
                    + learnerid
                    + "/val2="
                    + courseid
                    + "/val3="
                    + session_id + "";

            System.out.println("Stats from URL : " + url1);

            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            jsonstring = sh.makeServiceCall(url1, ServiceHandler.GET);

            System.out.println("Response: " + jsonstring);



            if (jsonstring != null && jsonstring.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    JSONObject questionsObject = new JSONObject(jsonstring);

                    JSONArray questionsArray = questionsObject
                            .getJSONArray("Table");
                    if (questionsArray != null && questionsArray.length() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < questionsArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject innerQuestionObject = (JSONObject) questionsArray
                                    .get(i);

                            String count = innerQuestionObject.getString("Count");
                            String result = innerQuestionObject.getString("Result");

                            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("R")) {
                                correctanswered = count;
                            } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("Total Questions")) {
                                totalquestions = count;
                            } else if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("W")){
                               // notanswered = count;
                                wronganswered = count;

                            } 

                          /*  if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("W")){
                                wronganswered = count;
                            }*/


                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please try after some time",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }



            return url1;




        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //p.dismiss();


                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            System.out.println("In onpostexecute status");
            // p.setVisibility(View.GONE);



            tvbookmarkcount.setText(totalquestions);
            //tvquesunattempted.setText(notanswered);

            tvcorrectanswered.setText(correctanswered);
            tvwronganswered.setText(wronganswered);

        }

    }
```

Comment: You've put your `p.dismiss();` in comment. Any reason why? Because that should stop your progressbar.

Answer (score 1):

try below code:-

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        p.dismiss();
     }
```

you must call dismiss when your task is complete (onPostExecute).